# Git adding files to repo

Tags: git, github

I followed basic Git tutorial and added README file, which worked. Then I copied my project files to the same folder and tried to add them to repository by running

```
git add --all
git ci 'test' (my alias for commit)
git push origin master
```

and nothing got pushed.

What are the commands I should run to push my files to the remote repository (master)?

I tried to commit changes and run status but it says 'nothing to commit'. It does not recognize, that I copied lots of new files to that folder..

OK, so I type: git add .   (get no response from console)
then type to commit, and says no changes..

Comment: Can you update your question to include the contents of your `.git/config` file? I'm guessing the remote url is invalid.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555551/how-to-add-files-to-github-repo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had an issue with connected repository. What's how I fixed:

I deleted manually .git folder under my project folder, run git init and then it all worked.

Answer (score 121):

This is actually a multi-step process. First you'll need to add all your files to the current stage:

```
git add .
```

You can verify that your files will be added when you commit by checking the status of the current stage:

```
git status
```

The console should display a message that lists all of the files that are currently staged, like this:

```
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   README
#   new file:   src/somefile.js
#
```

If it all looks good then you're ready to commit. Note that the commit action *only* commits to your local repository.

```
git commit -m "some message goes here"
```

If you haven't connected your local repository to a remote one yet, you'll have to do that now. Assuming your remote repository is hosted on GitHub and named "Some-Awesome-Project", your command is going to look something like this:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/Some-Awesome-Project
```

It's a bit confusing, but by convention we refer to the remote repository as 'origin' and the initial local repository as 'master'. When you're ready to push your commits to the remote repository (origin), you'll need to use the 'push' command:

```
git push origin master
```

For more information check out the tutorial on GitHub: http://learn.github.com/p/intro.html

Comment: @Stewie: After doing `git add <your_files>`, what does `git status` show you?

Comment: I think it's a problem with a repository..I tried git push, but it says Error: repository not found, did you enter it correctly?  How do I retype it?? I am so lost now..

Comment: @Stewie: did you try the [official tutorial](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gittutorial.html)? I think it will help you to understand some concepts used by git.

Comment: so I run now git init under my folder it says 'Reinitialized existing Git repository in....' Then I try to follow steps, and says that repository not found..

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't connected your local repository to a remote repository yet. I've updated my answer to give you a better understanding of how that works.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Are you sure the git process is in the directory of the git repo, rather than where it starts. ie: `C:/project/git_repo` rather than `C:/` ?

Comment: @ninjascript this works flawlessly! there's no more joy than watching your local file reflected in git repo! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

`git add` puts pending files to the so called git 'index' which is local.

After that you use `git commit` to commit (apply) things in the index.

Then use `git push [remotename] [localbranch][:remotebranch]` to actually push them to a remote repository.

Comment: Minor correction: the [refspec parameter](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) should be the local branch. Optionally, you can use `local_branch:remote_branch`, and a few other variations (even a commit SHA).

Answer (score 2):

After adding files to the stage, you need to commit them with `git commit -m "comment"` after `git add .`. Finally, to push them to a remote repository, you need to `git push <remote_repo> <local_branch>`.

Comment: I tried, but it says no updates.. It does not recognize, that I copied lots of new files to the folder.. and git push says 'everything is up to date', even I dont see my files on the repository..

Comment: No problemo, anything that helps ;-)

Comment: how to get .git file inside my root project folder?

Comment: @Kaveesh : u need to run a git init 1st. You should take a look at the free ebook Pro Git which explains it pretty well ;) : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Answer (score 1):

my problem (git on macOS) was solved by using 
`sudo git` instead of just `git`
in all `add` and `commit` commands