# Adding files to a GitHub repository

Tags: git, github

How do I add files to my GitHub repository? I'm using Windows and all my project files are in one folder and I just need to upload it to my repo.

Answer (score 31):

The general idea is to add, commit and push your files to the GitHub repo.

First you need to clone your GitHub repo.
Then, you would git add all the files from your other folder: one trick is to specify an alternate working tree when git add'ing your files.

```
git --work-tree=yourSrcFolder add .
```

(done from the root directory of your cloned Git repo, then `git commit -m "a msg"`, and `git push origin master`)

That way, you keep separate your initial source folder, from your Git working tree.

---

Note that since early December 2012, you can create **[new files directly from GitHub](https://github.com/blog/1327-creating-files-on-github)**:

[image: Create new File]

> **ProTip™**: You can pre-fill the filename field using just the URL.
>   Typing `?filename=yournewfile.txt` at the end of the URL will pre-fill the filename field with the name `yournewfile.txt`.

[image: d]

Comment: The commit and push part are actually detailed in GitHub support page http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/

Comment: Ack, that's a bit evil for a newbie. Maybe just instead copy the files to your Git repository then git add .

Comment: Good Guy VonC, Updating an answer, even though it wont probably ever be accepted. Kudos to you!

Comment: I keep getting this fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree when doing this git --work-tree=yourSrcFolder add .

Comment: @OutOFTouch are you in the git repo?

Comment: @VonC Please see this question I just created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531580/how-do-i-add-files-from-another-directory-with-git

Comment: @VonC i am new in github, i had created a repository, i know how to add some text/html files, but how can i add png image file for my project.??

Comment: @mans you can add it to your local clone, and push it back to your GitHub repo. But you couldn't create/add it directly on GitHub.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Git GUI on Windows, see instructions:

1. Open the Git Gui (After installing the Git on your computer).

[image]

2. Clone your repository to your local hard drive:

[image]

3. After cloning, GUI opens, choose: "Rescan" for changes that you made:

[image]

4. You will notice the scanned files:

[image]

5. Click on "Stage Changed":

[image]

6. Approve and click "Commit":

[image]

7. Click on "Push":

[image]

8. Click on "Push":

[image]

9. Wait for the files to upload to git:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open github app.
Then, add the Folder of files into the github repo file onto your computer (You WILL need to copy the repo onto your computer. Most repo files are located in the following directory: C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\GitHub\REPONAME)
Then, in the github app, check our your repo. You can easily commit from there.