# Local branches are identical even when I change one

Tags: git, git-branch

My IDE is showing me the same files in all branches. Even if I create a new class in branch "A" when I checkout branch "B" the class is there.

I haven't committed or pushed anything. My IDE is PhpStorm.

Any idea?

Comment: Yep, that's what I'd expect if you haven't committed anything. You have to tell Git about files if you want it to start tracking them. `git status` will probably tell you that all your files are unmanaged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding files to a GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555551/adding-files-to-a-github-repository)

Comment: _"I haven't committed or pushed anything"_ - there's your problem. You have not actually changed any branch, you just have some changes in your working tree.

Answer (score 0):

This is because **the new class (such as `class.php`) is untracked by git repo**.

When you created the new class `class.php` in `branchA`, but it was not committed in `branchA`. When you switched to `branchB`, the untracked file `class.php` will always show in working directory no matter which branch you checkout.

If you want the `class.php` only version controlled in `branchA`, you just need to switch to `branchA` and commit the changes:

```
git checkout branchA
git add class.php
git commit -m 'add class.php in branchA'
```

Now when you switch to `branchB` again (`git checkout branchB`), you will find the `class.php` will disappear.