# How do I manually deploy files to a working tree?

Tags: git

I have read articles about automating deployment of files to the working tree of a git repository.
Just out of curiosity, how do I do that manually after I pushed all my changes to my remote repository?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7047782/579580

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152607/git-force-push-current-working-directory/7152800 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `post-receive` **hook** , see http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

For example in your `repo.git/hooks/post-receive`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Deploy wd"
git --work-tree=/route/to/wd --git-dir=/your/route/to/repo.git checkout –f
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is in github you should use their webhooks.

[github webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)